# Почему невозможна запись в базу данных?

Tags: python, python-3.x, gunicorn

Я сделал веб-приложение с фронт эндом на react и бэк-эндом на flask, связанные с помощью api-запросов.
По аналогии из [этого вопроса](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64493492/how-do-i-deploy-flask-api-react-frontend-microservices-to-google-app-engine-wi) и [этого](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/how-to-deploy-a-react--flask-project) блога я задеплоил свой сайт на Google Cloud Platform.

На сайте есть возможность авторизации и регистрации. Авторизация проходит успешно, потому что это чтение из БД SQLite. А вот регистрация, то есть запись в БД происходит с ошибкой, что видно по логам:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему происходит ошибка

```
"sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) attempt to write a readonly database"
```

Деплой произодится из venv, а yaml файл выглядит вот так:

```
runtime: python37

env_variables:
  env: flex
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT api:app

handlers:
# frontend
- url: /static
  static_dir: build/static
- url: /(.*\.(json|ico|js|html))$
  static_files: build/\1
  upload: build/.*\.(json|ico|js|html)$

# backend
- url: /.*
  script: auto
```

Можете помочь решить проблему? Я думал, что gunicorn не может писать в БД, поэтому запускал от рута, но он по-прежнему не может писать в БД, только читать

Answer (score 0):

Оказывается, файловая система GCP работает только на чтение, что и рассказано в [этом ответе](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63017101/8313610).